# Cannot Update PHP DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to figure out why my data is not updating to mysql. I believed the issue was somewhere between the two files I displayed below. However, the issue was a syntax error in the $sql update - missing a couple of commas. After receiving feedback from the community, I went back and validated the form with javascript and php.

update.php.

```
<title>update</title>
</head>

<?php

session_start();
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pwdpwd", "pet_shop")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("pet_shop")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['GroomingID'];



// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM grooming WHERE GroomingID = '$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<body>


<table width="1200" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="6"><strong>Update Porting Details</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Address</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>City</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>State</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Zip</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Pet Type</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Breed</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Pet Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Neutered Or Spayed</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Pet Birthday</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName" value="<?php echo $rows['FirstName']; ?>"size= "15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="LastName" type="text" id="LastName" value="<?php echo $rows['LastName']; ?>"size= "15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="Address" type="text" id="Adress" value="<?php echo $rows['Address']; ?>"size= "15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="City" type="text" id="City" value="<?php echo $rows['City']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="State" type="text" id="State" value="<?php echo $rows['State']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="Zip" type="text" id="Zip" value="<?php echo $rows['Zip']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" id="PhoneNumber" value="<?php echo $rows['PhoneNumber']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" value="<?php echo $rows['Email']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="PetType" type="text" id="PetType" value="<?php echo $rows['PetType']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="Breed" type="text" id="Breed" value="<?php echo $rows['Breed']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="PetName" type="text" id="PetName" value="<?php echo $rows['PetName']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="NeuteredOrSpayed" type="text" id="NeuteredOrSpayed" value="<?php echo $rows['NeuteredOrSpayed']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="PetBirthday" type="text" id="PetBirthday" value="<?php echo $rows['PetBirthday']; ?>" size="15"/>
</td>
<tr>
</table>
<input name="GroomingID" type="hidden" id="GroomingID" value="<?php echo $rows['GroomingID']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, the last file - update_ac.php. I am getting an error that the file is not updating.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if ($_SESSION['username'])
        echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'>logout</a>";
    else
        die("You must be logged in!");
    //Session login - all admin pages must include this to interact with DB.
    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pwdpwd", "pet_shop")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("pet_shop")or die("cannot select DB");

    // update data in mysql database 
    $sql="UPDATE grooming SET FirstName='".$_POST['FirstName']."',
    LastName='".$_POST['LastName']."',
    Address='".$_POST['Address']."', 
    City='".$_POST['City']."', 
    State='".$_POST['State']."', 
    Zip='".$_POST['Zip']."', 
    PhoneNumber='".$_POST['PhoneNumber']."',
    Email='".$_POST['Email']."', 
    PetType='".$_POST['PetType']."', 
    Breed='".$_POST['Breed']."', 
    PetName='".$_POST['PetName']."', 
    NeuteredOrSpayed='".$_POST['NeuteredOrSpayed']."',
    PetBirthday='".$_POST['PetBirthday']."' WHERE GroomingID='".$_POST['GroomingID']."'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql)or
    die ("<br>Could not Update");


    // if successfully updated. 
    if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='Welcome.php'>View result</a>";
    }

    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: How does it not work? What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this? And bad programming practices are bad programming practices even when you're just doing it at home for fun. Today's fun project is tomorrow product. *Always* do it the right way when it comes to security.

Comment: "Please be nice:" how about you be nice to us and not just dump walls of code with little explanation.

Comment: Does it output an error? Try echo'ing out your query, does that return something when testing it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Check the return value of your query after every call, and if it's false look at mysql_error() to find out what the database is complaining about. Do this as a matter of course on every call to the database.

Comment: You may not care about the security aspect of SQL injections, but your database does. If one of the fields leads to a syntax error (that's all the required escaping is about, btw) then: no database update. Seeing that this is your described problem, you may wish to consult `mysql_error()` after all.

Comment: It's good practise to put the values in the update query under eachother, instead in a row like that, because you can easy see what you are updating. Now you have a very long line of update query you have to scroll through. Just put them under each other, every variablename and update value.

Comment: Can you put under `$sql` with the query just an `echo $sql;` and see what it returns. Then put it in phpmyadmin and run it.

Comment: @JohnConde I was first trying to see if I could edit entries, then going back to prevent sql injections

Comment: @Dagon Okay. My issue is after I click the submit button in update.php. The database is not updating and producing a fail message that i created. The fail message is found on update_ac.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a comma inbetween `PhoneNumber=...` and `Email=...` in your `UPDATE` statement.

Oh, and `NeuteredOrSpayed=...` and `PetBirthday=...`.

Also take note of the comments; protect your database and implement some debugging in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I am working on that part now.